# Getting Execution failed for task ':buildJsApps' error when building Spartacus storefront code in the cloud

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I have successfully created the spartacus store in my local using npm and angular cli. When I moved the same to our cloud, I am getting the below error while building the application:-
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':buildJsApps'.

  > Process 'command 'yarn'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the error by adding a stack trace or error log.

Comment: During build I am getting the below error:- FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildJsApps'.
> Process 'command 'yarn'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':buildJsApps'.
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:187)

Comment: at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'yarn'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Thank you for this. I do have one problem. What is your `buildJsApps` task? Maybe if you ran it with the `--debug` flag you might get a more usable log.

Answer (score 0):

If it's similar to what we've experienced, it might be related to dependencies.

If the error says something about babel, it was raised here: https://spartacus-storefront.slack.com/archives/CD16V16FR/p1584744427389300 The fix was to change the version of the dependency:

```
 ...
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/compat-data": "7.8.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "7.8.0",
        "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
        ...
    },
    ...
    "resolutions": {
        "@babel/preset-env": "7.8.0"
    }
```

If not, it could be related to the Angular version, where the latest 8.x causes the error, and the fix may be to downgrade:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.803.25",
    "@angular/cli": "8.3.25"
```